# What is wrong in this command "series(diff(f(z), z), z = 1, 2)" in Maple?

Tags: series, maple

Assume `f(z)` is an arbitrary function of `z`. In Maple, if we want to get the series expansion of `diff(f(z),z)` at `z=0`, we can use

```
series(diff(f(z), z), z = 0, 2)
```

The output is "(D(f))(0)+...". However, we cannot obtain the series expansion of `diff(f(z),z)` at `z=1` by

```
series(diff(f(z), z), z = 1, 2)
```

The output is "Error, (in PDEtools/useD/diff_to_D) invalid input: diff received z+1, which is not valid for its 2nd argument." What is wrong, and how to get the series expansion of an expression that contains derivatives of a function such as `diff(f(z),z)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug.

Workarounds might include,

```
series(D(f)(z), z = 1, 2);
                                         /       2\
     D(f)(1) + @@(D, 2)(f)(1) (z - 1) + O\(z - 1) /
```

or (with a different expansion order option),

```
MultiSeries:-series(diff(f(z), z), z = 1, 3);
                                         /       2\
     D(f)(1) + @@(D, 2)(f)(1) (z - 1) + O\(z - 1) /
```